# How to get root using Windows installer for 10.04 LTS desktop?

Tags: installation, root

I used Windows installer for installing 10.04 LTS desktop. When I try `sudo password root` and enter login password it gives `sudo: password: command not found`.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? What do you mean by "get root"? This expression can mean many different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sudo passwd root` command.

It is not password. It is `passwd`

But enabling root account is not a recommendation on Ubuntu.

Then If you want to log on as root, use

`su root`

Comment: It works, Thanks! I like Ubuntu and this community. The response was really fast.

Comment: your welcome friend but search on this site before you post a question :)